# What options do I have for preprocessing data before entering it into a convolutional neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network, data-preprocessing

So I am using about 1300 lines of statistical data from the 2017-2018 NHL season and I want to run it through a neural network, but I want to know what kind of pre-processing options I have. I have heard of normalization and mean subtraction, and so I did both of those to my data, and I was just deciding whether or not to balance and scale my data, but I realized that there is a lot more that I could do and am unaware of.

I have seen countless tutorials doing many different things with data before entering it, from people doing absolutely nothing to people running KPSS tests to value decomposition and I really just would love a clearer picture on what I need to achieve with the preprocessing stage and ways to achieve it. I know this is a broad question but any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From my experience be careful with preprocessing. Preprocessing can affect how your regression is done and if machine learning can learn the values correctly. I have a regression over a dynamic model that didn't like the normalization of the output over the training data but required normalization of the input data.

Comment: Wilmer Ariza so you trained your data without normalization, but then tested with normalization? wouldn't the values be completely different? or am I missing something here

Comment: The data for trainig was conformed of X and Y, the structure was X(normalized)-> Y(no normalized). But that depends on your system and machine learning.

Comment: @WilmerAriza wouldn't you have to de-normalize the data then? That sounds kinda counter intuitive to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of pre-processing techniques available like 'KS test', 'Z-score', min-max, 'T-test' etc. It depends on the type of data that what type of test can be applied to it. Go through this link, hope it will clear your doubt.
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_determine_the_appropriate_pre-processing_technique_for_artificial_neural_networks_ANNs